# Query SQL Server with IN (NULL) not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, table-variable

When I define a "User-Defined Table Type", as:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[BitType] AS TABLE(
    [B] [bit] NULL
)
```

I place 0 and null in this table-variable.
Then I do this query:

```
SELECT something FROM theTable WHERE item IN @theBitTypeTable
```

Will only get `item=0` not `item is null`

Simply put: `SELECT something FROM theTable WHERE item IN (0, NULL)` is not working (no error although)
It has to be `SELECT something FROM theTable WHERE item=0 OR item IS NULL`

So, my question is, if I like to use **User-Defined Table Type**, but I also need to use NULL value. How can I perform the query correctly to get result include null item.

Thanks (btw, I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only valid comparison operations with `NULL` values are `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, others always return false (actually - Unknown, see the @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment)

So, try the following

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[BitType] AS TABLE(
    [B] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)
GO
declare @theBitTypeTable BitType

insert @theBitTypeTable
VALUES(0), (2 /* instead of NULL*/)

SELECT something FROM theTable WHERE IsNull(cast(item as tinyint), 2) IN (select B from @theBitTypeTable)
```

Comment: Good idea, so instead of create BitType, maybe I need to create a TinyintType table variable, then I do not need to cast. Will try

Comment: Yup, the datatype's size is just the same, so you will not lost in performance, but'll gain in versatility

Comment: The other comparisons *don't* return `false`, they return `unknown`. The difference is readily apparent if you place a `NOT()` around such a comparison - `NOT (1=NULL)` isn't `true`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The other comparisons don't *return* `UNKNOWN`, they evaluate to `UNKNOWN` e.g. postgreSQL has partial support for Standard SQL's `BOOLEAN` type but uses `NULL` as a placeholder for `UNKNOWN`, so it may be said for that product that such comparisons evaluate to `UNKNOWN` (a logical value) but *return* `NULL` (a data value).

Answer (score 5):

Null does not equal null in SQL Server (and most other database management systems). You would need to do a coalesce on the joined column, and use a sentinel value to represent nulls.

Answer (score 4):

There is a cheat use `isnull` on the item being compared.

eg

```
SELECT something 
FROM theTable 
WHERE ISNULL(item,0) IN (0)
```